# How to order comments in firebase firestore by createdAt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document in which there is a comments array of objects and each object has createdAt property. I want to sort all the comments that are inside the comments array using the createdAt property, so, a new comment comes to the top.

I did some research and found that we can do this in [firebase's real-time database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) but I want to do the ordering of data using firestore.

Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
// firebase import
import { doc, onSnapshot, orderBy, query } from "firebase/firestore"

import { db } from "../firebase/config"

export const useDocument = (c, id, o) => {
  const [document, setDocument] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  // realtime document data
  useEffect(() => {
    let docRef = doc(db, c, id)

    if (o) {
      docRef = query(docRef, orderBy("createdAt", "desc")) // this is not working
    }

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      docRef,
      (snapshot) => {
        // need to make sure the doc exists & has data
        if (snapshot.data()) {
          setDocument({ ...snapshot.data(), id: snapshot.id })
          setError(null)
        } else {
          setError("No such document exists")
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err.message)
        setError("failed to get document")
      }
    )

    // unsubscribe on unmount
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [c, id])

  return { document, error }
}
```

createdAt property:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `doc()`? Doc references a single document, returning a DocumentReference. So your `snapshot.size` is 1 - there's nothing to order by. Ordering a CollectionReference in `query` will work as expected.

Comment: "I have a document in which there is a comments array of objects and each object has createdAt property." -> does this mean your comments are not documents within a (sub-)collection but a field in a single document?

Comment: yes! I have comments as a field(array of comment object) in a document, it's not a  separate document or sub-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`query()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#query) function takes a query as parameter and not a DocumentReference. Also the `orderBy()` clause *orders documents* when fetching multiple documents from a collection and not array elements.

To order array elements, you first need to fetch that document and then manually sort the array.

```
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
  docRef,
  (snapshot) => {
    // need to make sure the doc exists & has data
    if (snapshot.data()) {
      const orderedArray = snapshot.data().comments.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt.seconds - b.createdAt.seconds);
    } else {
      setError("No such document exists")
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message `TypeError: a.createdAt.getTime is not a function`

Comment: @r007 are you sure `createdAt` field is present in all array elements? Try using `a.createdAt?.getTime()`

Comment: yes! I have a `createdAt` field in all array elements. I also tried this `?.` but still got the same error. I attached the screenshot of the `createdAt` property, please check.

Comment: @r007 yes so that's a [Firestore Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#seconds) I missed that. Try `a.createdAt.seconds - b.createdAt.seconds`